# Xamarin jar binding

Tags: android, jar, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to bind jar from [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/549119/Encryption-Wrapper-for-Android-SharedPreferences) site. And I have gone through [xamarin jar binding documentation](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_(.jar)/) very carefully. I have updated metadata file present in Transform->metadata in xanarin's project as follows

Metadata.xml

```
<metadata>
    <attr
        path="/api/package[@name='com.securepreferences']/class[@name='SecurePreferences']/method[@name='edit']"
        name="managedReturn">Android.Content.SharedPreferencesEditor
    </attr>

</metadata>
```

After adding this I am getting error as

`Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'SharedPreferencesEditor' does not exist in the namespace 'Android.Content' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (CS0234) (securePreferences)`

In order to resolve this error what are the steps do I need to follow?? any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be `Android.Content.SharedPreferences.Editor`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html

Comment: I did that now error is `The type or namespace name 'SharedPreferences' does not exist in the namespace 'Android.Content'`